# Date above 10 days in query

Tags: mongodb

How can you translate this query in mongodb :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_sales
where DATEDIFF(day,sale_date,getdate()) > 10
```

I have this kind of structure :

```
{
_id:5f82f25fc56f9c02dde4743f
origine:"Shops"
checksum:"1708c16ad9420e5d06785ebf562946f3"
create_date:2020-10-11T11:54:07.722+00:00
sales_date:2020-10-22T13:33:43.427+00:00
exception:""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $lt: [
               { $subtract: ["$sales_date", "$create_date"] },
               { $multiply: [10, 1000, 60, 60, 24] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wgISxqX4qZv)

Note, your sample data has a difference of 11 days, so above query does not return the document.

Comment: Thanks. You're my guest